# How to escape a double-quote in a TSV file for import into a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, csv

How does one specify a cell to contain exactly one double-quote character in a TSV file so that it will be handled correctly ***when imported*** (as a spreadsheet) into Google Sheets?

(Note: when importing the file, **Tab** rather than **Automatic** *must* be specified as Separator Character in the import dialog; if I don't do this, the imported sheet has even more problems.)

I have tried all of the following, without success

```
"
'"
""
'"'
```

I also tried manually inserting a lone double-quote character in one cell of a Google Sheets, and then downloading the spreadsheet and inspecting the downloaded file.  Frustratingly enough, the downloaded file shows a lone double-quote character (i.e. not escaped in any way) between the flanking tab characters.

<sup>BTW, this means, among other things, that Google Sheets cannot do the download-re-import round trip.  E.g. if the spreadsheet I downloaded is re-imported (exactly as it was delivered by Google Sheets) into a Google Sheets (specifying tab as a separator character in the import dialog), the formatting is messed up; the lone double quote apparently has the effect of escaping the subsequent tab, so the import does not recognize it as a separator.</sup>

I stress that what I'm looking is for how to write the TSV so that it gets imported correctly into a Google Sheets.  IOW, simply entering the double-quote manually into a Google spreadsheet *is of no use* here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try four double-quotes, e.g.

```
""""
```

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) there is no reliable standard, but some attempts have been made.

```
A (double) quote character in a field must be represented by two double quote characters.
```

Comment: Amazing.  I wouldn't have guessed this one in a million years.  Three double-quotes is *maybe* understandable (as in "the outer quotes quote the middle one"), but four of them makes no sense to me.  But it works!  Thanks!

Comment: @kjo 4 makes sense because the 1st opens the string 2nd and 3rd is the escaped quote and the 4th closes the string.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the double quote in the original file with something unique, the concatenated word doublequote. Then I imported into Google Sheets and it went ok. Then I went to the Find dialog and entered doublequote. In the Replace dialog, just entering the " replaced correctly. Entering '" (a single quote followed by a double quote) also replaced correctly. Entering two double quotes, "", did not replace correctly, it replaced the word with the two double quotes. Before I was getting 8k cells with lots of aggregated cells, and now I got clean 17k cells as in my original.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a little nodejs tool to build a tsv that has fields contining double-quotes. Pasting the tsv into an empty google sheet would only work if i escaped the double-quotes by replacing them with two double-quotes. The answer above saying four double-quotes didn't work for me. Maybe things have changed since 2012?

E.g. the text...

`She said "Hey that's my horse".`

should be

`She said ""Hey that's my horse"".`

The javascript escaping code:

```
fieldtext = fieldtext.replace(/"/g, `""`)
```